# on button click retrieve first 5 arraylist record and so on

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist

In my application I am having listview.I want to display first five records from my arraylist and when user click button then load more 5 . my aaraylist size is 25. i can get first 5 records but how to retrieve next five.any help?

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newbrnd=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(AuthorizedServiceCenter);
                final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newbrnd_=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



                if(AuthorizedServiceCenter.size()>5)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                    {

                        newbrnd_.add(newbrnd.get(i));
                        newbrnd.remove(i);

                        Log.e("details..", ""+newbrnd_.toString());
                        Log.e("remove", ""+newbrnd.get(i));

                    }

                }

                loadMore1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {

                        for(int i=5;i<10;i++)
                        {
                            newbrnd_.add(newbrnd.get(i));
                            newbrnd.remove(i);

                            Log.e(" details..", ""+newbrnd_.get(i));
                            Log.e(" remove.", ""+newbrnd.get(i));

                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: please show what You have done...

Comment: please write the full code i.e where you have set the adapter on the listview.